# Russian-english / english-russian dictionary

Tags: ipod-touch, software-recommendation, search, dictionary

Could anyone propose any RU-EN/EN-RU dictionary application compatible with iPod 1g (iOS 3.1.3)?

Paid or free, doesn't matter, but need some good one (with big amount of words and handy/fast UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like LangBook. Not sure though if it works with iOS 3.x. It says 'iOS 4.0 tested', but I don't think this means 'do not work with 3.x'.

Comment: It is a iOS 3.1 requirement, which is perfect for me. Thanks.